# Contently default locale showing in JSON

Tags: javascript, locale, contentful

In the following video it's explained that fields will automatically use the default locale if only 1 locale is available: https://www.contentful.com/developers/bits-and-bytes/#localized-content-in-your-contentful-application

I'm using the `contentful-management.js` API.

However, when I run
`space.getEntries({ "sys.id": id })` I get `{title: {en-US: "Some text"}}` in return. My expected outcome would be `{title: "Some text"}`.

Even when I send `space.getEntries({ "sys.id": id, locale: "en-US" })` I get the same result.

This happens for both `getEntries` and `getEntry`.

"Enable localization of this field" has not even been enabled on the "Content model".

Does the behaviour in `contentful.js` differ from `contentful-management.js` or is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer and `contentful-management.js` does not automatically handle localization and therefore differs from `contentful.js`

Comment: You probably need to manually keep track of the current language, although it's a bit frustrating.

Comment: Especially if you're using typescript, where you then need custom types for your only locale